# How to add space between strings in Python List without the underscore

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am learning Python and was playing around with lists. This is my code:

```
current_list = "Red_shirt Blue_shirt Blue_Jeans Black_Jeans Black_Jacket"

print("Is that all you got?")

thislist = current_list.split(' ')


while len(thislist) != 10:
    more = input("> ")
    newlist = ["%s" % more]
    next_one = newlist.pop()
    print("Adding: ", next_one)
    thislist.append(next_one)

print(thislist)
```

So when I input the new strings and append them, there's no problem with having spaces between words (ie. the items of the list).

However I was wondering if there was something I could do with the current_list variable to come out as [Red shirt, Blue shirt, ... ] instead of [Red_shirt, Blue_shirt, ...] ?

Thanks for any advice. I accept answers from either versions of Python to know more.

Edit: I'm sorry if I busted somebody's nerves by asking such a "basic" question, but it would be great if I wasn't voted down for no reason. There was no question on here about this and I was wondering if I was missing something with variables to get to my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split your string first with space then loop over the split list and split the words with `_` then you can use `join` function to join them with space :

```
>>> [' '.join(i.split('_')) for i in current_list.split()]
['Red shirt', 'Blue shirt', 'Blue Jeans', 'Black Jeans', 'Black Jacket']
```

Or as a more elegant way suggested in comment by @HughBothwell you can use `str.replace` :

```
>>> [i.replace("_", " ") for i in current_list.split()]
['Red shirt', 'Blue shirt', 'Blue Jeans', 'Black Jeans', 'Black Jacket']
```

Comment: You could also use `str.replace("_", " ")`.

Comment: Sweet this worked. I had a feeling it had something to do with the join function. I was still looking if there was some sort of escape character I could've used while declaring the current_list variable so I wouldn't have to add the underscore there. Thanks!

Comment: @OrangeLime welcome! the `replace` method be recommended as its more efficient for this task!